# Kinetic.js: Rotating image on touch

Tags: javascript, math, animation, kineticjs

I have this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDjpx/2/

The image is not rotating correctly.
The code that i used was:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'd',
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var isDragging = false;
var refRotation = null;

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    offset: [50, 50],
    dragOnTop: true,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {

        var xd = 150 - pos.x ;
        var yd = 150 - pos.y ;
        var theta = Math.atan2(yd, xd);
        var deg = theta * 180 / Math.PI;

        if (!isDragging) {
           isDragging = true;
           refRotation = deg;
        } else {
            var rotate = deg - refRotation;
            rect.setRotationDeg(deg);
        }

        return {
            x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
        }
    }
});
```

layer.add(rect);
stage.add(layer);

Anyone know what is wrong with my Math???

## --- EDIT ---

New feddle with what i wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/zk9cn/

Comment: i don't think there's nothing wrong with your math. it's rotating correctly. when you said incorrect, what does it do and what is expected. the only thing i notice is the closer the cursor to the rectangle, the weirder it get; but it's because there is no handle. if you rotate while moving on the red rectangle border. it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about Math.atan2, but it seems calculation of x and y is not right to me. I would  deduct position from center, not center from position.  http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/qZDcg/

```
    var x = 150 - pos.x;
    var y = 150 - pos.y;
    var radian =  Math.PI + Math.atan(y/x);
    this.setRotation(radian);
```

Other thing, I also see your variables are not in use;  isDragging, refRotate, and rotate.

----- Edit ----

If you want to rotate rectangle by picking up the corner, you can use the following code.
When you pick up the corner, degree calculated by center positon is already 45. That's why you cannot pick up the corner properly. By adjusting 45 makes it seem right, but when you pick up the straight line, it will go wrong again. It seems your requirement has a flaw in it unless it's intentional.  http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/7Q5Hd/

```
    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var xd = 150 - pos.x ;
    var yd = 150 - pos.y ;
    var theta = Math.atan2(yd, xd);
    var degree = theta / (Math.PI / 180) - 45;
    this.setRotationDeg(degree);
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not correct too. What i want, is click at a square corner and move, and i want that the corner rotate with the mouse. At this feddle, the mouse is rotatig faster...

Comment: didn't not know what exactly "not rotating correctly" meant. updated the answer.